# golang reusing methods of struct

Tags: go

I am learning go and was looking at a simple go example web app:
https://github.com/campoy/todo/blob/master/task/task.go

Having struct:

```
    type Task struct {
        ID    int64  // Unique identifier
        Title string // Description
        Done  bool   // Is this task done?
    }
```

and

```
    // TaskManager manages a list of tasks in memory.
    type TaskManager struct {
        tasks  []*Task
        lastID int64
    }
```

There are methods on the TaskManager 
    func (m *TaskManager) Save(task *Task) error ...
    func (m *TaskManager) All() []*Task...

I am wondering how to generalize TaskManager into Manager, so it would have these same methods (namely: save, all, find) so it can be used on different structs, for example Users, which would all have ID field.

I assume constructing an array of general type doesn't fit because there is an ID in 'save' and 'find' methods

Answer (score 3):

Go doesn't have generics (for now, at least), but you still can perform what you want (not 100%) by using an interface.

```
type Manager interface {
  Save(interface{}) error
  All() ([]interface{}, error)
}
```

Of course, it doesn't come for free and you need to do some error handling in your `TaskManager` to implement the interface, example:

```
func (m *TaskManager) Save(t interface) error {
  task, ok := t.(Task) // type assertion
  if !ok {
    // return error invalid input type
  }
  // do the rest as normal...
}
```

:Example for comment

```
type Entry interface {
  SetID(int64)
  GetID()int64
}

type Task struct {...}

func (t *Task) SetID(id int64) {...}
func (t *Task) GetID() {...}

func (m *TaskManager) Save(e Entry) error {...}
```

More info on interfaces:
* http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types
* http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types
*http://golangtutorials.blogspot.com/2011/06/interfaces-in-go.html

Comment: Thanks for your writeup. But, that is still not clear to me. The part, 
 t.(Task) could be any struct with Id, for example 't.(User)' or 't.(Video)'.  It looks to me as if it's implementing "Save" on Task only, while I'd like Save on any of the structs.

Comment: The point is you will have `TaskManager` for `Task` and `UserManager` for `User`. Both `TaskManager` and `UserManager` are `Manager`. There is no simple (see package reflection) way to tell you if a struct have the `Id` field or not.

Comment: Any way you can define an `Entry` interface with `SetID, GetID` and let `User/Task` implement it. Then `Manager` with `Save(Entry)` etc...

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to write an [interface](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types) for structures that have an ID, then generalize your Manager to operate on elements of that interface instead of elements of a specific struct.